# encrypt aws ebs volume with an existing aws kms key using boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

How to encrypt an existing AWS EBS volume with an existing AWS KMS key?

The KMS encrypt method allows encrypting a plaintext but i want to encrypt a volume.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this with boto 2 but obviously, boto2 don't support this.

I found this can be done only with boto 3 :

http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#ec2.Client.create_volume.

Thanks.